# Creating a to-be-determined amount of objects using loops

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to accomplish this using an array of objects which is probably stupid but I am up for suggestions.

```
while(Boolean == True){
    Class[] object = new Class[99]; // 99 is just a place holder
    object[j].setAttribute1 = stringInput;
    object[j].setAttribute2 = intInput;
    j++;
}
```

The way I'm going about this is probably awful.  I've tried this with both the object declaration in and out of the loop.  I just really want to know if there is a way to go about this and have it work without having to individually declare every single object.

Comment: Can you explain what it is that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: You should move "Class[] object = new Class[99];" outside of the loop.

Comment: If your code is not coherent, at least be clear about what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `ArrayList`, which was created with dynamic growth in mind:

```
List<Class> objectList = new ArrayList<>();

while (someBoolean == true) {
    Class object = new Class();
    object.setAttribute1(stringInput);
    object.setAttribute2(intInput);
    objectList.add(object);
}
```

If you want to find out how many elements were added to your list, you can call `objectList.size()`.

Comment: This loop will never break.

Comment: And you should never use `_boolean == true`.

Comment: Neither will OP's, it's clearly placeholder code